# SQL Server export to Excel

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3, excel

How to increase performance on exporting a database with tables with one to many relationship (in so case many to many relationship) into a single excel file.

Right now, I get all the data from the database and process it into a table using a few for loops, then i change the header of the html file to download it as an excel file. But it take a while for the number of records i have (about 300 records. )

I was just wondering, if there is a faster way to improved performance.

Thanks

Comment: There are any number of potential issues here.  A few questions: Is everything supposed to go into a single worksheet in excel or are you doing multiple worksheets?  Second, Why do you have to do a few loops?  Sounds like you are issuing at least 1 additional query per record.  If it's going into a single worksheet, then it would be better to just pull everything in a single query.   Please elaborate on what it is you are actually doing and what the expected output is.

Comment: How are you "exporting" the data?  You could probably de-normalize the data in a single SQL statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're loading each table into memory with your c# code, and then building a flat table by looping through the data.  A vastly simpler and faster way to do that would be to use a SQL query with a few JOINs in it:
<strike>http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp</strike>
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)

Also, I get the impression that you're rendering the resulting flat table to html, and then saving that as an excel file.  There are several ways that you can create that excel (or csv) file directly, without having to turn it into an html table first.

Comment: Please don't link to those people, they are not a good source. See http://w3fools.com/